# How to get text that appears on hover to display in very center of div (horizontally and vertically)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a website, working on some things I've learned by studying html and css. I am trying to make an image stay within the container but appear as it's "zoomed in" on the hover, and then to have text appear on hover as well. I have the first part, the "zoom", but for some reason or another I cannot get the text to stay centered. A few times I've gotten it centered, but as soon as I change the screen resolution or try it on a different device it fails. How can I get the text to appear horizontally and vertically centered within a hovered image that is contained within a div? I would also like to add a small color filter, but that is something I'll figure out once I get the text centered. Here is one specific example of what I am looking at doing:
https://www.quadlockcase.com/ -- the section where it has the "shop" elements, when you hover over top, text appears centered. I can't seem to figure it out through inspecting either.

I've looked through StackOverflow for quite some time, unfortunately to no prevail. I'm sure there may be an answer out there, but for some reason when i'm trying to have everything 'zoom' together, the fact that I am containing the image within the div and the text within that image just doesn't seem to work. I hope this isn't something that has an obvious answer elsewhere, I really just am stuck on it. [Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkw7o2sg/1/), as well as the code below

```css
 body {
        background-color: grey; /* Color so you can see picture scale */
      }
      .box { /*container to hold items */
        width: 20%; 
        margin: 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }
      .imgBox { /*image box to contain image within the .box class */
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
      }
        .imgBox:hover { /* add a small border with a drop shadow on hover */
          filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.6))
          drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.6));
        }
    
      .imgBox img { /*actual image within the image box, so it stays within div */
        display: block; /* no whitespace */
        transition: .3s ease-in-out;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        margin: auto;
      }
        .imgBox:hover img { /* scale image but keep it within box on hover */
          transform: scale(1.2);
        }
      .hovertext { /* text I want to appear centered on hover */
        display:none;
        clear:both;
        text-align: center;
        color:white;
        font-size: 1em;
        width: 100%;
        bottom:0;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:2;
        vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .hovertext:hover {
            display: block;
            opacity: 1;
        }
      .imgBox:hover .hovertext{ 
        display: block;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="box"> 
        <div class="imgBox">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="lorempixel">
              <p class="hovertext">Product Name</p>
            </a>
          </div>  
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix (that retains most of your existing HTML and CSS) would be to adjust the CSS for `.hovertext` as shown:

```
.hovertext {
  /* text I want to appear centered on hover */
  display: none;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;

  /* bottom: 0; <-- remove */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;

  /* Reset margin of p to 0 to enable correct vertical centering */
  margin:0;

  /* Position from to of parent by 50% height */
  top:50%;

  /* Offset a further 50% by height of the this element's height */
  transform:translateY(-50%);

  /* vertical-align: middle; <-- remove this */
}
```

Here's a working snippet:

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  /* Color so you can see picture scale */
}

.box {
  /*container to hold items */
  width: 20%;
  margin: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.imgBox {
  /*image box to contain image within the .box class */
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.imgBox:hover {
  /* add a small border with a drop shadow on hover */
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)) drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6));
}

.imgBox img {
  /*actual image within the image box, so it stays within div */
  display: block;
  /* no whitespace */
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.imgBox:hover img {
  /* scale image but keep it within box on hover */
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.hovertext {
  /* text I want to appear centered on hover */
  display: none;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  
  /* bottom: 0; */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  
  margin:0;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  
  
  /* vertical-align: middle; */
}

.hovertext:hover {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.imgBox:hover .hovertext {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="imgBox">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="lorempixel">
      <p class="hovertext">Lorem ipsum.</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This did exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the explanations as well with the html code -- very much appreciated ...edit/ just read that I'm not supposed to comment to say thank you. Sorry about that https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers...

Comment: You're very welcome, all the best with your project :)